# Difference between system bus, address bus and data bus?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems

What is the difference between system bus, address bus and data bus?
Are they different wires or they are using same wires but logically different?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is what data they carry.  An address bus carries addresses (e.g., which address the CPU wants to load from memory).  A data bus carries data (e.g., the value the memory found at that address).  A system bus carries addresses, data, and control: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_bus